# What is the scope of let when used without in?

Tags: haskell, let

In a Haskell tutorial I ran across the following code:

```
do [...]
  let atom = [first] ++ rest
  return $ case atom of
```

Note that the `let` expression does not have an `in` block. What is the scope of such a `let` expression? The next line?

Comment: `[first] ++ rest` is quite odd, too, should be `first : rest`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply put, it's scoped "from where it's written until the end of the `do`".

Note that within a `do` statement, `let` is handled differently.

According to http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monads_as_computation#Do_notation , it is interpreted as follows:

```
do { let <decls> ; <stmts> }
  = let <decls> in do { <stmts> }
```

Answer (score 8):

The scope is the rest of the `do` block.

[See §3.14 of the Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) (specifically, the fourth case in the translation block). (Yes, this is the section about `do` blocks, because `let` without `in` is only valid inside a `do` block, as Porges points out.)

Comment: Note also that `let` without `in` is only valid inside a `do` block.